# C# Process is not stopping

Tags: c#, process

I am using the below code C# Process instance to do a CSV import for PostgreSQL.

```
Process process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"cmd.exe",
        Arguments = $"/c cat \"{filePath}\" | psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U {user} -d {dbname} -w -c \"copy data_temp from stdin csv header\"  ",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    }
};

process.Start();
string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Dispose();
```

It works but I look in task manager and after a while there is lot of PostgreSQL processes running and eventually the database gets locked.

Am I not closing the process down properly?  How can I ensure it doesn't stay open?

Comment: Not to directly solve your problem, but getting into the habit of using `using` blocks around `IDisposable`s will make your life a little easier.

Comment: Does that do anything more than call `.Dispose()`?

Comment: Open up a cmd window manually and then type > help cmd to get a list of options.

Comment: Try to add a eventhandler instead of calling the WaitForExit() method. You can do it by doing the following: process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; process.Exited += [yourEventHandlerHere]. In your eventhandler, dispose your process.

Comment: Are you expecting that `.Dispose()` will close the process?  That's now how it works.  It just holds onto a process handle that's eventually disposed, but it's not "disposing" the process itself.  It's up to the process that was called to close after it runs (or for you to do something else to force it closed).

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is specific to PostgreSQL cli and not issue with calling code.

Comment: A `using` block will ensure that `Dispose()` is called, even if there is an exception.  In your code, an exception may result in your `Dispose()` never being reached.

Comment: ahh good point, this could be what was happening

Answer (score -1):

Not to sure if this could help or not but here are two examples I have of killing processes via msiexec and Exe.

Uninstalling Msiexec.exe files…

```
Process x = new Process();
x.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
x.StartInfo.Arguments = "/qb /x {81681F4C-83F1-4F22-9AEB-C7DA7C372EA2}";[quiet uninstall] 
x.Start();
x.WaitForExit();
```

and

Uninstalling exe (file path method, not msiexec)

```
Process a = new Process();
a.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_5_0; //defined in a string before hand. 
a.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
a.Start();
a.WaitForExit();
```

You can try making the filename a string that is defined before instead of having it as @"cmd.exe", that might help!